# Using a planogram for Yolo7 object detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, yolo

I am using Yolo7 for object detection on a personal project designed to help grocery stores and supermarkets... One of the main functionalities is using a Planogram, so after a picture is processed it needs to be compared to the Planogram and I don't really know what's the best way to do it. I currently am able to detect shelves and the products they contain and I classify them like this :

```
analysis = {'Shelves': 4, 'Shelves data': {1: [439.0, 533.0], 2: [315.0, 435.0], 3: [141.0, 322.0], 4: [0.0, 138.0]}, 'Products': {'Product1': [2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4], 'Product2': [2, 2]}, 'Product count': {'Product1': 13, 'Product2': 2, 'Total': 15}, 'Products per shelf': {2: {'Product1': 6, 'Product2': 2}, 1: {'Product1': 3}, 4: {'Product1': 3}, 3: {'Product1': 1}}, 'Percentage': {1: {'Product1': '100.00', 'Total percentage in relation to all detected products': '86.67', 'Total percentage of the same product ': '23.08'}, 2: {'Product1': '75.00', 'Total percentage in relation to all detected products': '86.67', 'Total percentage of the same product ': '46.15', 'Product2': ('25.00', {'Total percentage in relation to all detected products': '13.33', 'Total percentage of the same product ': '100.00'})}, 3: {'Product1': '100.00', 'Total percentage in relation to all detected products': '86.67', 'Total percentage of the same product ': '7.69'}, 4: {'Product1': '100.00', 'Total percentage in relation to all detected products': '86.67', 'Total percentage of the same product ': '23.08'}}, 'Versus Competition': {2: [{'Product2': {'Product1': '7'}}, False]}}
```

I thought about processing the image of the planogram and comparing the .txt results with each picture, however I'm not sure it will provide the best results.

Could you help me implement the Planogram ?

Comment: what is the actual question ?  where are you stuck ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am unable to implement the planogram

Comment: what have you tried so far?  what are you expecting ?

Comment: Currently I ran the planogram once by the Object detection AI, then retrieved results. After saving the results, each time I run the AI, I loop through the .txt results files, get the data and run it through a for loop, get the last two values (box height and weight) and get the middle point and store them and order them. then I compare them to the same values from the planogram... 
It's not accurate so I'm asking for a better way if there is one...